# Risk of Delete the LDF file in sql server 2008 r2

Tags: sql, logging, ldf

I am a developer and my manager want me to delete all the LOG file (LDF) for all database in sql server.

please tell me what are the risks if i delete the Log file of a database

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here [SQL Server Log Files](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/sql-server-log-files) you can find what log files are good for . If your manager thinks you never need the transaction log, then **good night**, you can/will loose the integrity of your data.

And here [Safely deleting a SQL Server log file (.LDF)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13757/safely-deleting-a-sql-server-log-file-ldf) you will find more about the risks.